# How to import google app engine sqlite datafile?

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlite, google-cloud-datastore

I have downloaded one of my entities from Google App Engine using the remote API and their appcfg.py script.  Now I have a file that looks to be a mix of binary and text.  (That is, I recognize words like *create table* and my field names, but the file is about 50% unprintable characters.)

Now I would like to import that file (users.sqlite) into an sqlite database on my computer (Mac OSX), but I can't quite seem to figure out how to do so.

Sample (failed) transcript follows:

```
sqlite> .import users.sqlite users
Error: no such table: users
sqlite> .import users.sqlite
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "import". Enter ".help" for help
sqlite> .restore users users.sqlite
Error: cannot open "users.sqlite"
sqlite>
```

I've [attached a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaoQN.png) of the first portion of my datafile (displayed in TextMate with "show invisibles" on) to show what I mean about mixed text & binary.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Well nevermind.  It turns out to be FAR easier to [follow these instructions (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader) ] and get the data as a csv via the bulkloader.yaml  Voting to close the question (too localized -- "don't do that.")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing Sqlite data into Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870379/importing-sqlite-data-into-google-app-engine)

Comment: rds: not a duplicate -- this is that question, but backwards.  That is, I'm trying to EXPORT data from GAE and import it locally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`users.sqlite` *is* an SQLite database. Your data is stored in it as entities - serialized Protocol Buffers in App Engine's internal format - however. If you need to access your data directly, you're better off downloading it as CSV.

Comment: "users.sqlite is an SQLite database"  Aha!  No wonder I couldn't import it.  :)  Well, I eventually got it as CSV, but it's good to understand why I couldn't read users.sqlite -- thanks!